# Apply event listener to multiple KMLlayers in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I want to apply the event listener to multiple layers (i.e.: numbered layer1 to layer 8), tried doing an array and doesn't work. The KMLlayers fire only when you turn them on so maybe an array isn't the correct way but not sure how else.

```
if (document.mapControlBox.checkbox1.checked) { 

    /* Load the layer */
    var layer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer('theURL', {suppressInfoWindows: true});
    layer1.setMap(map); 
    layer1.set('preserveViewport', true); 

};

    /* repeat, repeat... */

     /* try to select all layers */
for (var i = 1; i < layer.length; i++) {
    var layers = layer[i];
 google.maps.event.addListener(layers, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    showContentWindow(text);
  });
}

        /*default function from Gmap example */ 
  function showContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('content_window');
    sidediv.innerHTML = text;
  };
```

The associated HTML:

```
    <form name="mapControlBox">
    <ul>

        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" onclick="displayMaps();" />
          <label class="mapoption">Checkbox1<label>
        </li>
                  /*etc etc*/
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I decided to go with this script:
http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/kml-shapes.html

But nonetheless my issue with my version was that I had to call variables globally.